# Regular expression using finder

Tags: python, regex

I trying to figure out this expression:

```
p = re.compile ("[I need this]")
for m in p.finditer('foo, I need this, more foo'):
    print m.start(), m.group()
```

I need to understand why I'm getting "e" in count 22
and re-write this correctly.

Comment: you should tag a language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` denotes a character class, that is, in your case, [I need this] would stand for: match a character that is one of: I, n, e, d, t, h, i, s, and, (maybe) a space. It is equivalent to `[Inedthis ]`. If you would like to match the whole phrase, omit the brackets. If you want to match the brackets, as well, escape them: `\[I ... \]`.

Comment: I needed that. I have a better understanding of brackets.

Answer (score 2):

By using `[]`, you are searching for the character class `[ Idehinst]`, that is the set of the characters `' ', 'I', 'd', 'e', 'h', 'i', 'n', 's', 't'`.

Using `(...)` matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, and indicates the start and end of a group.

If you want to search for the group: `(I need this)`.

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile ("(I need this)")
>>> for m in p.finditer('foo, I need this, more foo'):
...     print m.start(), m.group()
... 
5 I need this
```

For more information, see [7.2.1. Regular Expression Syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) in [the official documentation](http://docs.python.org/).